# How to get only first member of tail instead of all lists?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement tail function by myself. I took some help from online because I am totally new to Haskell so I found this:

```
tails' :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails' [] = []
tails' (x:xs) = xs : tails' xs
```

For `tails' [1,2,3]`, this will return `[[2,3],[3],[]]`. I am trying to get only `[2,3]`.

Answer (score 3):

I just finished by doing this:

```
tails' :: [a] -> [a]
tails' [] = error "List is empty"
tails' (x:xs) = xs
```

Comment: Good start. Can you improve the error message? Alternatively, can you think of something reasonable to return when the list is empty?

Comment: Did you mean to call the function `tail'`? This only gets one tail.

Comment: @AwaisHussain: dfeuer is hinting that there is a built-in function called [`tails`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) that returns a list of lists, whereas your function should just be called `tail'` since it resembles the built-in function called `tail`.

Comment: @dfeuer Updated error message. And I wanted only one tail so it just returns one tail only.